# Cordova project can't remove plugin after update my project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to upgrade my Cordova Ionic project ios platform from 3.0.1 to the newest 4.5.2 using xcode 9. I remove the ios platform and re-add it again under CLI 7.1.0. Then I restore all the .xcodeproject settings by copy the old .xcodeproject into the new ios platform and reset all the path necessary in the workspace. Luckily my project build successfully and runs fine in the debug mode.

However when I am trying to upgrade some out of date plugins in the new project, I found that I can only "add" plugin, which everything just goes fine. But when I am trying to remove any plugin (whether they have been added in the new workspace or not), the CLI always show red font message: Error: Could not find *-Info.plist file, or config.xml file.

This message will also show up if I tried to run ionic prepare ios command. Interestingly enough, if I use the .xcodeproject file cordova originally generated, then all the things will just work fine.

Any idea on what specific settings is wrong so that the CLI could only recognize the new .xcodeproject file but not the old .xcodeproject file?

---

To answer "why don't want to use the new .xcodeproject automatically generated". My project is pretty huge which contains 4 different targets and each of them have different project settings. First of all, CLI don't know that and will only generate one target and I have to duplicate it another 3 times. Secondly, it will be such a pain to restore each target settings one by one. And thirdly the new project doesn't contain any changes in the iOS native code I made such like in appDelegate class. Therefore I just want to find a trick way to make it through.

Comment: I see some similar question but without answers in the following links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246127/error-could-not-find-info-plist-file-or-config-xml-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183033/cordova-ios-adding-extension-error-could-not-find-info-plist-file-or-config Hopefully these guys can get their answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova creates the files automatically, I believe copying a file generated from an old version and pasting a new one will **break your project**.

What happens if you remove the platform, add again but without reusing the .xcodeproject? The normal thing is that you got to work normally.

Another option would be to *upgrade* Cordova or a *downgrade*, using **nvm** you can have several versions of Nodejs and Cordova.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my duty is to update the ios platform into a higher cordova version. I have tried both of your suggestions already. 1. if I remove and re-add, I lost lots of settings in the .xcodeproject file so that my app can not be compiled properly. 2. I am asked to use the newest cordova version so this is not a choice for me. The project is quite big, it has 4 different build targets and each of them has different build settings and build phases. As you can imagine, it will be unwise to restore them hand by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned in your question how you are removing the ios platform , try to do them as follows:

```
cordova platform remove ios
```

`cordova platform list` here you can verify that ios platform deleted

```
cordova platform add ios --save
```

I don't know what version you are using but cordova 6.5.0 should solve the ios-build issues. you can install using like below:

```
sudo npm i -g cordova@6.5.0
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, if I put the .xcodeproject automatically generated by the Cordova in the iOS platform root, then everything work fine. (In here when I say "automatically generated" I mean do the exact same things you mentioned in the answer.) Therefore it is not a build issue at all. My problem is, how to modify the "old" xcodeprject file so that it can fit into the new workspace.

Comment: @n4feng here there are 2 questions 1.Why do you want to change the old xclodeproject because on every build you will be getting those filesautomatically.2.What changes youare referring ?

Comment: "1. if I remove and re-add, I lost lots of settings in the .xcodeproject file so that my app can not be compiled properly" --quote from command in the previous answer. 2. Any changes that can let the Cordova CLI recognize the old .xcodeproject file without throwing the error message

Comment: @n4feng ah got it , then you need to be looking at the hooks , which adds them directly after build , so that which works the way you needed